# How Should I Tackle My Routine?

Tags: running, weight-loss, workout-routines, cardio

I am a 14 year old female, a little over 5'4 (162 cm), and weigh about 175 lbs (79 kg).

Recently, I realized that I needed to get in shape and be healthy. I've got a lot of physical problems to overcome, but I'm motivated to do it.

I know I need to work on training my heart and muscles around my lungs, as well as my leg muscles and stretch my hamstrings, so I've made a routine of some light jogging/running everyday and it's been a big help.

However, I want to do more than fix my cardio. I'm not talking about some 6-pack abs or a mega toned body, I mean having some decent muscles, especially in my abdomen. I've got very large breasts, however (32DD), so exercise, especially crunches and push ups are very hard and painful.

Can anybody suggest a good routine for this, and if my running routine is actually doing me good when sometimes I can barely move my legs or stand?

Comment: Overlap with this question. http://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/14376/3778?

Answer (score 1):

Yea Allyson! You are young and have already started getting on the right track.
You write that you have "got a lot of physical problems to overcome" so make sure that you have cleared anything that you need to clear with your doctor.

- This question/answer about [getting back in shape](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/12860/beginner-in-physical-fitness-need-tips-and-advices/12864#12864) will give you some good steps to take that includes cardio, postural or core strengthening, flexibility and measurements to keep motivated besides just weight.
- If you are having too much trouble with your legs from running you may be going for too much too soon. [Couch to 5K](http://www.c25k.com/) can give you a plan. As others have said, aquatic exercise can be a good way to exercise that is non-impact and prepares your muscles and tendons for more strenuous workouts.  See: [how to pool run.](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6894/what-is-the-a-proper-way-to-pool-run/6909#6909) Many beginners to exercise overdo, get injured and give up. So progress gradually and give your body recovery time.
- As for breast size interfering with your workouts,  you can get some pretty good workouts with resistance bands. That may be an easier way to begin strength training than starting with bodyweight exercises.
- As @Android points out, sports and activities add enjoyable fitness into your lifestyle with social contacts who also enjoy fitness.
- Nutrition:  Don't forget that any healthy lifestyle includes healthy foods in healthy proportions.  Look at your daily routine to find where you can cut out unnecessary sugars like soft drinks and processed foods etc. The biggest changes you can make in your body composition is with proper diet (not a fad diet) in conjunction with exercise.

Congratulations on a good start. Enjoy your results.

Answer (score 1):

Cycling is a wonderful cardiovascular exercise and it limits bouncing and impact (assuming you're on smooth paved roads or groomed trails mostly) which helps with some larger breast issues AND is gentler on your limbs than running.

Running is nicely complimented by cycling and you may see that you have less pain in joints if you supplement your cardio training with a bike.  That said, proper form and mechanics are essential to each sport.

Good luck and have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Swimming is a good general exercise, as it will work most of your muscle groups, but if you just want to work your core try a combination of: Squats, [Planking](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2014/07/31/plank-variations-ab-workout_n_5630203.html), and a few [Crunch variations](http://homegym-exercises.com/variation-frog_situp_butterfly_crunch.html).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with arober11, swimming is a good exercise, especially when you are "a little over" and because you "can barely move your legs or stand", it is very joint-friendly and of course it also trains many muscle-groups at the same time.

I would also recommend you to do a litte strenght workout, even it is only once or twice a week --> you don't have to do push-ups, there are much easier exercises to do, maybe you search the web. But do a whole body workout, not only for example your abdominals. (correct strength-training can also increase your mobility (use the whole range of motion))

In my opinion other disciplines like tennis, volleyball, badminton... are also very good because they are not that monotonous like running and they also train many muscle-groups at the same time and also coordination... . But like running they are not very joint-friendly.

However most important is that you have fun what you do and that you do it regularly.

I hope I could help you with my answer.